# RealmProxy files are not being generated

Tags: android, realm, parceler

I have been using `Parceler` to serialize `RealmObjects`. After updating to version 1.2.0 of Realm, none of the RealmProxy classes are being generated.

I have cleaned and rebuilt the project several times unsuccessfully. Here is a snippet of the `parceler`.

`@Parcel(implementations = {TrackRealmProxy.class},
        value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
        analyze = {Track.class})`

Comment: There is no reason why it shouldn't generate the RealmProxy classes, do you get any error messages? Do you by chance have instant run on (you should turn it off)?

Answer (score 1):

**Update as on Realm 5.0.0**

full package name is required with `_` separator.

it will look like

```
import io.realm.com_example_test_SomeClassRealmProxy; 


@Parcel(implementations = {com_example_test_SomeClassRealmProxy.class},
value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
analyze = {SomeClass.class})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including a default empty constructor that doesn't have any parameters? Parceler has some issues without that default constructor.

`class A(){
    int attributeA;
    float attrubuteB;
}`